# Why is "gave" aorist in John 17:6, in contrast to others as listed?

Tags: john, word-study

John 17:2 "whom you have given him".. dedokas, perfect.

John 17:6 "whom you gave me" ...........       **edokas, aorist.**

John 17:6 "you gave them to me"..........**.edokas, aorist.**

John 17:9 "whom you have given me".. dedokas, perfect.

John 17:24 "whom you have given me". dedokas, perfect.

John 6:39 "of all he has given me"......... dedoken, perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 2 cents.

The perfect was on its way out of the language and could at times be used without any particular reason (Blass/Debrunner §340 and §343).

John uses it much more than the synoptics (§340: "on account of the solemn and emphatic style of John.")

That is my caveat emptor. Nonetheless, I think a case can be made for a deliberate differentiation in these verses. My assumption in the following is that the aorist is the norm (unmarked) and the perfect is "marked", meaning, "it can very well mean something here."

The perfect denotes the continuance (perfect) of a completed (aorist) action. (Blass/Debrunner §340)

The  aorist of "give" is just stating a fact. This is common in narratives. The perfect would then denote that the effect of the "giving", lived on. "It was given to me, and I have it."

Jn 17:2
Καθὼς ἔδωκας αὐτῷ ἐξουσίαν πάσης σαρκός, ἵνα πᾶν ὅ δέδωκας αὐτῷ δὠσῃ αὐτοῖς ζωὴν αἰώνιον.

Just as you gave (narrative aorist, stating a fact) him power over all flesh, in order that everything you gave (perfect: gave him, and he still has it) he may give (aorist subj.) them (all flesh).

Jn 17:9
Ἐγὼ περὶ αὐτῶν ἐρωτῶ, οὐ περὶ τοῦ κόσμου ἐρωτῶ ἀλλὰ περὶ ὧν δἐδωκἀς μοι, ὅτι σοἰ εἰσιν, …

I am asking (praying) about them, not asking/praying about the world, but about those who you gave (gave, and I still have them) because they are yours…

Jn 17:24
Πἀτερ, ὅ δέδωκἀς μοι, θέλω ἵνα ὅπου εἰμὶ ἐγὼ κἀκεῖνοι ὦσιν μετ῾ ἐμοῦ, ἵνα θεωρῶσιν τὴν δὀξαν τὴν ἐμἠν, ἥν δἐδωκἀς μοι ὅτι ἠγἀπησἀς με πρὸ καταβολῆς κὀσμου.

(Textual problem here but it doesn’t affect the perfect)
Father, that which you gave me (perfect: gave and I still have), I desire that wherever I am, that even these are with me, that they may see my glory that you gave (perfect: gave me, and I still have) because you loved me (aorist: narrative) before the foundation of the cosmos.

Apologies for miss-typed Greek. I had to battle to get my editor to turn off auto-correct.

Aorist: gave

Perfect: gave for keeps

Comment: Re: John 17:6. "Yours they were, and you gave them to me," -Not for keeps, Christ will give back/hand over the kingdom to God the Father, 1 Cor 15:24?

Comment: @C.Stroud   That is the aorist in Jn 17:6, not the perfect. I was only commenting on the use of the perfect. The perfect is used in 17:6 on the verb τηρέω. The form of δίδωμι that you are translating is the aorist form, not the perfect, so I never meant for it to be understood as "for keeps". My apologies if I was unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the verb **δίδωμι** (didomi = I give) is extremely common in the the Gospel of John, especially in the 17th chapter where it occurs 17 times!  If we, as the OP suggests, include the surrounding verses of John 16:23, 18:9, 11, the number increases to 20 times.

Let us focus on the verses (as the OP's question implies) that deal with people being **given**.

- John 6:37 - Everyone the Father gives me (**present**)
- John 6:39 - those He has given me (**perfect**)
- John 17:2 - all whom You have given Him (**perfect**)
- John 17:6 - people whom You have given (**aorist**) Me ... and to Me You gave (**aorist**) them
- John 17:9 - those You have given Me (**perfect**)
- John 17:14 - I have given them Your Word (**perfect**)
- John 17:22 - the glory which You have given (**perfect**) Me, I have given (**perfect**) them
- John 17:24 - Father, those who You have given Me (**perfect**)
- John 18:9 - Those You have given Me (**perfect**)

Note that this is not all of the instances δίδωμι - there are 3 in John 17:2, another in V6, and another in V7, two more in V8, another in V11, and V12, an extra in V24, etc.

In reviewing this summary, one must recall that the primary function of the verb "Tense" in Greek (see Greek Grammar Beyond the Basics, D B Wallace) is **Aspect** and not time.  This is not to suggest that time is not relevant but that it is usually secondary to Aspect.

The perfect tense certainly presents an action that is completed.  The aorist "presents an occurrence in summary , viewed as a whole from the outside, without regard for the internal make-up of the occurrence." [Qoted in GGBB, page 554]

Viewed in this light, the aorist tense usually implies a past tense (but not always) but would in the case on John 17 since the action (the giving of people to Jesus) has already been described as a completed act in the surrounding text.

Thus, aorist in John 17:6 is not out of place.

We should also note that while most of the instances of people being given to Jesus is in the perfect tense, the process, according to John 6:37 is on-going.